# Unable to use SMTP Gmail server to send email authentications

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, gmail

I am trying to send User email verification. I have updated the env and mail configuration to suit my Google Mail. However, I am encountering a `Swift_TransportException (530)` error.

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=okaydots@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=
```

**mail.php**

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'okaydots@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Kyle Jeynes'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('okaydots@gmail'),
    'password' => env(''),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend'  => false,
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
];
```

**User.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**HomeController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('verified');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

This is the exact error message I am receiving:

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError 133sm47765wme.9 - gsmtp "

After googling this error, I was told to [Turn on less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/lesssecureapps). After doing so, I still receive the same error. How can I allow Laravel to send email verification / emails?

Comment: Do you mean SMTP?

Comment: The error seems to indicate you need a password

Comment: Do you have 2 way authentication turned on for that account? Then you need to create an app password.

Comment: How can I create an app password? I think thats the issue because I am using my password I use to sign into Gmail atm @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Yeah, I mean SMTP - I monged it there, feel free to update Q @RiggsFolly

Comment: [Also Googleable](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)

Comment: You only need to create an app pasword If you _do_ use 2 factor authentication. So if you're not using 2 factor auth, then you can't (and don't need to) create an app password. If you do use it, then you need to google on how to generate an app pass.

Comment: That is [what I googled](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/lesssecureapps) @RiggsFolly

Comment: You keep linking to pages that you have to be signed into google to see. Thats not much help

Comment: You didnt say if you were Actually using 2FA or not on this account

Comment: Btw, the link in the error message have links about creating app passwords, so you don't even need to google for it.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MagnusEriksson after realising its an authentication error although my password was correct, and I wasn't using 2 step auth, I researched what `env()` did, which then resulted in me fixing this issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly it wasn’t even an authentication issue, yes, it contains links about the issue and its self explanatory but it was a code issue, i was overwriting the env() with the wrong data, i had to rollback my mail.php file and change the config only in my .env file, perhaps dont jump the gun and assume people haven’t yet tried to google the issue and check the credentials are correct

Comment: Please read the second comment. I say no more.

Comment: The password was fine, i removed it from OP so no one logged into my gmail lol the error provided me with a URL explaining I had incorrect credentials OR i needed to enable less secure apps, however, both - in this case - didn’t solve the issue so i posted on here. Turns out, my mail.php file uses the env configuration and i overrided it, it was searching for the field okaydots@gmail.com and thus returning null causing auth errors, i don’t see why the question entitles a downvote for a generic problem which i gave a MCVE for and there was no need to attempt to patronise me for it @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please revert back your `mail.php`. You only need to change your `.env`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=okaydots@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=     #use gmail app password not your gmail password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 0):

After intensive Googling, I found that the `mail.php` contains the `env()` method for the configuration, and therefore expects arg 1 to be the configuration name inside the `.env` file.

I changed my `mail.php` to this and now it works:

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'okaydots@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Kyle Jeynes'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'), # Changed
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'), # Changed
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend'  => false,
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
];
```